# Splitting Nucleotide Sequences in JS with Regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to split up a nucleotide sequence into amino acid strings using a regular expression.  I have to start a new string at each occurrence of the string "ATG", but I don't want to actually stop the first match at the "ATG".  Valid input is any ordering of a string of As, Cs, Gs, and Ts.

For example, given the input string: ATGAACATAGGACATGAGGAGTCA
I should get two strings: ATGAACATAGGACATGAGGAGTCA (the whole thing) and ATGAGGAGTCA (the first match of "ATG" onward).  A string that contains "ATG" n times should result in n results.

I thought the expression /(?:[ACGT]*)(ATG)[ACGT]*/g would work, but it doesn't.  If this can't be done with a regexp it's easy enough to just write out the code for, but I always prefer an elegant solution if one is available.

Comment: Two questions: 1. Isn't alignment on a three-codon-border important? 2. Do you always want a match from `ATG` up to the end of the string, i. e. "split" `ATGTTTATGGGGATGCCC` into `ATGTTTATGGGGATGCCC`, `ATGGGGATGCCC` and `ATGCCC`?

Comment: It can definitely be done :) just give us a minute to figure out how. Also, why do you want the first match to be the input string itself? You already have the input string...

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: 
1) My understanding is that it isn't.  My wife is the geneticist, I'm just trying to make a web app for her lab to use.  I'm getting the details from her as I go, but as I understand it a new string should start even if the "ATG" isn't on the border in the preceding sequence. 
2) I believe there are also "stop" codes that will stop the process, but I figured I'd just split the string on those codes up front before I started parsing.  Other than that, yes, continue to the end of the string as in your example.

Comment: @MvanGeest: The first match doesn't have to be the input itself, that's just how I was envisioning the regex working, since that's what the logical pattern is.  Either way works though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use regular expressions, try this:

```
var str = "ATGAACATAGGACATGAGGAGTCA",
    re = /ATG.*/g, match, matches=[];
while ((match = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    matches.push(match);
    re.lastIndex = match.index + 3;
}
```

But be careful with `exec` and changing the index. You can easily make it an infinite loop.

Otherwise you could use `indexOf` to find the indices and `substr` to get the substrings:

```
var str = "ATGAACATAGGACATGAGGAGTCA",
    offset=0, match=str, matches=[];
while ((offset = match.indexOf("ATG", offset)) > -1) {
    match = match.substr(offset);
    matches.push(match);
    offset += 3;
}
```

Comment: +1 - Darnitall! I was in the middle of my post, explaining the behaviour of match and exec as defined in the ECMAScript 3rd edition (which defines that the next iteration carries on from *endIndex+1*, not *lastIndex+1*).  I'd got that part down and decided to test my solution, similar to your first, in the developer tools console.  Didn't realize I had an error in my code, got stuck in an infinite loop and had to close the window.  Came back and you'd added the solution to your post already lol. The line *"You can easily make it an infinite loop."* is just teasing me now!

Comment: Yeah, I was going to use a solution similar to the first one there, I was just curious if there was a more elegant solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want is

```
var subStrings = inputString.split('ATG');
```

KISS :)

Comment: But that leaves out the 'ATG' sections which the user wants to include in his result.

Comment: Every result but the first one will naturally have been preceded by 'ATG'. Concat them back on if you need them.

Comment: From the post: 'I have to start a new string at each occurrence of the string "ATG", but I don't want to actually stop the first match at the "ATG".'

Sure, I could do a series of concats after doing a split, but that's not what I was looking for.  Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting a string before each occurrence of `ATG` is simple, just use

```
result = subject.split(/(?=ATG)/i);
```

`(?=ATG)` is a positive lookahead assertion, meaning "Assert that you can match `ATG` starting at the current position in the string".

This will split `GGGATGTTTATGGGGATGCCC` into `GGG`, `ATGTTT`, `ATGGGG` and `ATGCCC`.

So now you have an array of (in this case four) strings. I would now go and take those, discard the first one (this one will never contain nor start with `ATG`) and then join the strings no. `2 + ... + n`, then `3 + ... + n` etc. until you have exhausted the list.

Of course, this regex doesn't do any validation as to whether the string only contains `ACGT` characters as it only matches positions between characters, so that should be done before, i. e. that the input string matches `/^[ACGT]*$/i`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to capture from every "ATG" to the end split isn't right for you. You can, however, use `replace`, and abuse the callback function:

```
var matches = [];
seq.replace(/atg/gi, function(m, pos){ matches.push(seq.substr(pos)); });
```

Comment: I started with `seq.replace(/atg(?=(.*))/gi, function(g0,g1){ matches.push(g0 + g1); });` - this one abuses the callback function *and* capturing groups within lookaheads. Too much.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't with regex, and I don't know if this is what you consider "elegant," but...

```
var sequence = 'ATGAACATAGGACATGAGGAGTCA';
var matches = [];
do {
    matches.push('ATG' + (sequence = sequence.slice(sequence.indexOf('ATG') + 3)));
} while (sequence.indexOf('ATG') > 0);
```

I'm not completely sure if this is what you're looking for. For example, with an input string of `ATGabcdefghijATGklmnoATGpqrs`, this returns `ATGabcdefghijATGklmnoATGpqrs`, `ATGklmnoATGpqrs`, and `ATGpqrs`.